# Load SVG shapes over multiple lines in D3

Tags: d3.js, svg

Data

```
MP,Party,Constituency,Status
"Abbott, Diane",Labour,Hackney North and Stoke Newington,Remain
"Abrahams, Debbie",Labour,Oldham East and Saddleworth,Remain
"Adams, Nigel",Conservative,Selby and Ainsty,Leave
```

I have created a svg group for each 'Party' populated with many circles to represent each 'MP' belonging to that Party.

The problem I have is that some of the parties are so large that they run right off the screen. Ideally I would like to set the width at about 10 circles before they return to the next 'line'.

I have found examples for setting the width of SVG text but not SVG shapes. Is it possible to create multiple lines of SVG shapes using D3?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vo2qEjdhva8oRCMf1rrx?p=info)

```
   var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)

    var chart = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(50,100)')

    var party = chart.selectAll(".party")
      .data(mps)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + (i * (height / mps.length) + ")")
      })

    party
      .append('text')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key
      })

    party.selectAll('.members')
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values
      })
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'chart')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr('cy', '10')
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return '#' + d.Color
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + i * 13 + ",20)"
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps? You'll likely have to adjust the values to suit.

```
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + ((i / 10) * 20)) + "," + ((i % 10) * (height / mps.length)) + ")")
```

Comment: Thank you! I've got this almost working with something similar https://plnkr.co/edit/vo2qEjdhva8oRCMf1rrx?p=info but I'm having trouble getting the lines completely straight and have a feeling this has to do with using index. Could you explain to me what (i / 10) and (i % 10) are doing?

Comment: i / 10 divides i by 10. i % 10 s the remainder when dividing i by 10

Comment: OK thanks, I'm closer to understanding but still can't figure it out. Is it possible get my straight line using this method?

Comment: The Plunker link above shows 12 groups each with their own set of circles. I want the circles to take a new line once they reach a certain number. Your method does this, thank you, but I can't get the circles to form straight lines (please see plunk). I also need a way to calculate the height of each group so that I have overlap between groups but this is in addition.